# Dismiss keyboard with TouchableWithoutFeedback - HighOrderComponent

Tags: javascript, react-native, high-order-component

I am trying to make a High Order Component that is supposed to wrap a component with TouchableWithoutFeedback in order to hide the keyboard whenever the user presses outside the keyboard.

My high order component looks like this:

```
const DismissKeyboardHOC = Comp => {
  return props => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
      <Comp {...props} />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
export default DismissKeyboardHOC;
```

In my LoginScreen I have wrapped it with my HOC:

`export default DismissKeyboardHOC(LoginScreen);`

The potential problem I am facing is that when I look at the inspector the TouchableWithoutFeedback ends up wrapping around my LoginScreen instead of wrapping around SafeAreaView(where it is supposed to be).

I have tried to manually put the TouchableWithoutFeedback in the LoginScreen and it works flawlessly but i doesnt work in my HOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) change child of TouchableWithoutFeedback to :

```
  <Comp style={{flex: 1}} {...props}>
    {children}
  </Comp>
```

2) change your export to :

```
export const DismissKeyboard = DismissKeyboardHOC(View);
```

NOTE: Import view from react native like this:

```
import {view} from 'react-native'
```

3) wrap your views in LoginScreen component with DismissKeyboard like this:

```
return(
<DismissKeyboard>
// All the children
</DissmissKeyboard>
)
```

Comment: Thank you bro! This solved it! I wish we worked in the same company! What an amazing person you are! Cheers!